# MISP automation key

Tags: malware, malware-detection

So I'm trying to automate the script that sending curl requests to MISP API ([misp-project.org](http://www.misp-project.org)).

The problem is that there is an **API KEY** which should be in **every** request and you can get it only by mannually copy-pasting it into your script from web-interface (https://misp_url/events/automation).

However, in this way script becomes hardwired to a sertain MISP server and a user.

Is there another way to get this API KEY?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab your user account details including your API keys via /users/view/me